# tvOS: UItableViewCell.detailsTextLabel not appearing when zero length string set as value

Tags: uitableview, uikit, tvos

Coming directly from the pages of tvOS WT* Magazine ...

I have a `UITableView` with a static cell. The cell has it's style set as *Right Detail* which adds two label instances (Acutally `UITableViewLabel`s) to the `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` properties. I'm also using a custom table view cell class so I can initialise the cell.

In my classes `awakefromNib` I am setting the value of the `detailTextLabel` like this:

```
NSString *detailValue = .... // loaded from somewhere else.
self.detailTextLabel.text = detailValue;
```

This is were it gets weird. If the `detailValue` is `nil` or `@""`, then the details label never appears on the UI. If I look at the UI through Reveal it's gone from the view hierarchy.

If I try and then set it like this:

```
self.detailTextLabel.text = @"abc";
```

It still never appears. And strangest of all, the `detailTextLabel` property has a `UITableViewCell` instance with a text value of `abc`, but a size of {0,0}.

However, if the initial value of the `detailTextValue` is set to a string of at least 1 character, then it functions normally, resizing itself as I update the values.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Did you show me your full method that you use in your project ?

Comment: It's normal and as expected, if the text is nil, the label wont have height or width, and if you need to give it value, you have to force the cell to relayout again by reload or begin/end update

Comment: Just reading elsewhere that this was a problem in iOS 8 and solved in 9. Looks like it still exists in tvOS 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding the following code when I set the label after initial display.

```
    if (self.detailTextLabel.superview == nil) {
        [self setNeedsLayout];
    }
```

Thanks for looking into this.